# script help to extract value

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have the following text file that I want to manipulate

```
add_journal_volume group="RPCG_VLS_PSALTUXP201" copy="TW_PROD_VLS" uid="60,06,01,60,01,d0,40,00,37,1e,85,5e,17,9c,ea,11" uid_hash="0xfd81565b74f160c3"  -f;
add_replication_volume group="RPCG_VLS_PSALTUXP201" copy="VNX057_CRR_PSALTUXP201" replication_set="RSet0" uid="60,06,01,60,0e,60,3c,00,16,f5,56,7f,02,d8,e8,11" uid_hash="0xd7c77496f2520fbc"  -f;
add_replication_volume group="RPCG_VLS_PSALTUXP201" copy="VNX057_CRR_PSALTUXP201" replication_set="RSet1" uid="60,06,01,60,0e,60,3c,00,18,f5,56,7f,02,d8,e8,11" uid_hash="0x62d865f2be9ff409"  -f;
```

Basically I just want to return as column delimited text using ";"

```
RPCG_VLS_PSALTUXP201;TW_PROD_VLS;;60,06,01,60,01,d0,40,00,37,1e,85,5e,17,9c,ea,11
RPCG_VLS_PSALTUXP201;VNX057_CRR_PSALTUXP201;RSet0;60,06,01,60,0e,60,3c,00,16,f5,56,7f,02,d8,e8,11
RPCG_VLS_PSALTUXP201;VNX057_CRR_PSALTUXP201;RSet1;60,06,01,60,0e,60,3c,00,18,f5,56,7f,02,d8,e8,11
```

The tricky part is those `add_journal_volume` line there is no `replication_set` so in that case I just want to leave it blank.

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
perl -lne 'my %f; $f{$1} = $2 while /(\w+)="(.*?)"/g;
           print join ";", @f{qw(group copy replication_set uid uid_hash)}'
```